# Is there a way to make controls transparent to mouse events in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mouseevent

Is there a way that I can let mouse events pass through to controls behind?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Sure, just set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the control. Mouse events will pass through it.

Comment: What if I want both to get the mouse events?

Answer (score 2):

I usually solve these kind of issues by adding handlers of child controls to the parent at construction. This way the 'click'-event for example activates a method that raises the 'click'-event of the parent.